# Notify javafx that contents has changed

Tags: scala, javafx

Here's a simple class, which I'm holding in a javafx `ListView`

```
class MyItem {
   var active: Boolean = true
   def toString = "Test"
}
```

I've made a custom listcell for `MyItem`

```
class MyCell extends ListCell[MyItem] {
  override def updateItem(item: MyItem, empty: Boolean): Unit = {
    super.updateItem(item, empty)
    if(item != null) {
      setText(item.toString)
      if(item.active) setGraphic(g1) else setGraphic(g2)
    }
  }
}
```

I've set this on a listview, but I would like the graphic to change along with the `active` var. If this were swing, I'd just call `repaint` when I change it, but this isn't an option.

Is there some way of notifying javafx of the change? Should I be structuring things differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making `var active` as `BooleanProperty` and add a `ChangeListener` on `active`. If this is on Java,

Modify model

```
class MyItem {
   private BooleanProperty active;

   public MyItem() {
        active = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
   }

   public BooleanProperty activeProperty() {
      return active;
   }

   public void setActive(boolean active) {
       this.active.set(active);
   }

   public boolean isActive() {
       return active.get();
   }

}
```

Modify update method:

```
super.updateItem(item, empty);
if (item != null) {
    setText(item.toString());
    item.activeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) setGraphic(g1);
        else setGraphic(g2); 
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to do a bit more than this. If the cell is reused to represent a item after previously representing a different item, it will still be listening to the old item (as well as the new one). So you need to arrange to remove the listeners as well.

Comment: @Lucas: You're welcome. But as what @James_D commented, you need to make sure that the `ChangeListener` that is associated to the `BooleanProperty` must be removed after showing the model to the view.